# VBA Search all sheets for double clicked cell value

Tags: vba, excel, events

The other day I learned how to use VBA to double click a cell in sheet1 and then it would jump to the cell with that same value in Sheet 2.

I have a similar report now, except this time I need to double click a cell in Sheet1 and then search every sheet in the same workbook for that value.

The code I have for the first scenario that works is here:
In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick _
(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub

'If the double-clicked cell isn't in column A, we exit.
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

'Calls the procedure FindName in Module1 and passes the cell content
Module1.FindName Target.Value

End Sub
```

In Module1:

```
Sub FindName(ByVal sName As String)
'Finds and activates the first cell
'with the same content as the double-clicked cell. sName
'is the passed cell content.
Dim rColumn As Range
Dim rFind As Range

'Activate the sheet Contact Data.
Worksheets("All Data").Activate

'Set the range rColumn = column B
Set rColumn = Columns("B:B")

'Search column B
Set rFind = rColumn.Find(sName)

'If found the cell is activated.
If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
   rFind.Activate
Else
   'If not found activate cell A1
   Range("A1").Activate
End If

Set rColumn = Nothing
Set rFind = Nothing

End Sub
```

If anyone knows how to maybe create a worksheet loop in this so that it will look for the value in every worksheet I will be so grateful!

Thanks!
Emmily
My Source for Previous code: http://www.sitestory.dk/excel_vba/hyperlinks-alternative.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. Will search all sheets and return a message if nothing is found. Will activate cell if it is found.

```
Sub FindName(ByVal sName As String)

    'Finds and activates the first cell in any sheet (moving left-to-right)
    'with the same content as the double-clicked cell. sName
    'is the passed cell content.
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set rFind = ws.Columns(2).Find(sName, lookat:=xlWhole) ' look for entire match, set to xlPart to search part of cell ... 2 is column B.

        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            Dim bFound As Boolean
            bFound = True
            ws.Activate
            rFind.Select
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    If Not bFound Then MsgBox sName & " not found in any sheet."

End Sub
```

Comment: The "Great Scotts" are in sync again.

Comment: @SCOTTHOLTZMAN Thank you so much for your fast response! I tried to run this code, I am getting an error on the very first line: Compile error: User-defined type not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: @Emmily - `Worksheet` in `Dim ws As Worksheet` had one too many `e`'s. I edited my code. Try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That solved that error. @ScottHoltzman I am sorry I am new to VBA so I am having trouble debugging for myself. on "rFind.Activate" I am given: Run-time error '1004': Activate method of Range class failed

Comment: I should add, the cell I am searching for is in a pivot table. I am not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: @Emmily - I changed `.Activate` to `.Select`. Activate was probably getting hung by the fact that the cell is on a different worksheet.

Comment: @Emmily - I also added `ws.Activate` before `rFind.Select`

Comment: Perfect, this worked. Thank you! sorry I didn't see your comments until now. Didn't realize there was a "Show more comments button"

Answer (score 4):

Change your second Sub to:

```
Sub FindName(ByVal sName As String)
'Finds and activates the first cell
'with the same content as the double-clicked cell. sName
'is the passed cell content.
Dim rColumn As Range
Dim rFind As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Activate the sheet Contact Data.
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Change the "Sheet1" reference to the sheet calling so it is excluded
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        'Set the range rColumn = column B
        Set rColumn = ws.Columns("B:B")

        'Search column B
        Set rFind = rColumn.Find(sName)

        'If found the cell is activated.
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
           ws.activate
           rFind.select
        End If
    End If
Next ws
Set rColumn = Nothing
Set rFind = Nothing

End Sub
```

This uses a `For Each` loop to cycle through all the sheets in the workbook.

See [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) for more info on for each loops.

Comment: hitting SO with a dose of double Scott again!  ... Ah yes, a dose of the "Great Scott's"!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Hi Scott, Thank you for your great answer. It runs through the code and seems to find the match but at "rFind.Activate" I am given: Run-time error '1004': Activate method of Range class failed. Any ideas? I had the same error on the other Scott's answer. The cell I am trying to look for is in a pivot table. Does that mess things up?

Comment: Yayy @ScottCraner Thank you! worked perfect! Wish I could Green check two answers, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find all instances of the search term in the whole Workbook, instead of just having to know that there is at least one occurance, you might want to check out Chip Pearson's FindAll method here:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx

You could utilize his FindAllOnWorksheets as follows:

```
Sub FindMyResults(ByVal sName as string)
    Dim Result as Variant
    Dim ResultRange as Range
    Dim N as Long

    Result = FindAllOnWorksheets(InWorkbook:=ThisWorkbook, _
        InWorksheets:="Sheet1:Sheet3", _
        SearchAddress:="$B:$B", _
        FindWhat:=sName, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False)

    For N = LBound(Result) To UBound(Result)
        If Not Result(N) Is Nothing Then 'There is at least one result
            For Each ResultRange In Result(N).Cells

                'Do something with your results.

            Next ResultRange 
        End If
    Next N

End Sub
```